# REGEX - Find and Replace

Tags: regex, replace, find

I am trying to perform a find and replace on blocks of text. I am looking for each block that opens with `<GenericEquipment>` and closes with `<\/GenericEquipment>`. I am able to do that with this:

```
<GenericEquipment>([\S\s]*?)<\/GenericEquipment>
```

If that block contains a certain piece of text ("Nokia AEUB"), replace specific lines.  What I have posted below works but it also changes some of those lines within blocks that DONT contain that piece of text...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Class FindAndReplaceServices

Public Sub FindAndReplaceEquipment(ByVal ocalcFile As String, ByVal revision As String)

    Try

        CreateSubDirectories(ocalcFile, revision)

        Dim saveAsNameAndLocation As String = GetSaveAsNameAndLocation(ocalcFile, revision)

        Dim originalOcalcFile As String = File.ReadAllText(ocalcFile.ToString)

        Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(originalOcalcFile, "<GenericEquipment>([\S\s]*?)<\/GenericEquipment>")

        For Each match As Match In matches

            Dim foundMatch As String = match.Value()

            If foundMatch.Contains("Nokia AEUB") Then

                originalOcalcFile = Regex.Replace(originalOcalcFile, "<VALUE NAME=""DescriptionOverride"" TYPE=""String"">Nokia AEUB</VALUE>", "<VALUE NAME=""DescriptionOverride"" TYPE=""String"">Samsung AT1K01</VALUE>")
                originalOcalcFile = Regex.Replace(originalOcalcFile, "<VALUE NAME=""Description"" TYPE=""String"">Nokia AEUB</VALUE>", "<VALUE NAME=""Description"" TYPE=""String""> Samsung AT1K01</VALUE>")
                originalOcalcFile = Regex.Replace(originalOcalcFile, "<VALUE NAME=""CoordinateZ"" TYPE=""Double"">708</VALUE>", "<VALUE NAME=""CoordinateZ"" TYPE=""Double"">710.75</VALUE>")
                originalOcalcFile = Regex.Replace(originalOcalcFile, "<VALUE NAME=""CoordinateZ"" TYPE=""Double"">648</VALUE>", "<VALUE NAME=""CoordinateZ"" TYPE=""Double"">650.75</VALUE>")
                originalOcalcFile = Regex.Replace(originalOcalcFile, "<VALUE NAME=""CoordinateZ"" TYPE=""Double"">588</VALUE>", "<VALUE NAME=""CoordinateZ"" TYPE=""Double"">590.75</VALUE>")
                originalOcalcFile = Regex.Replace(originalOcalcFile, "<VALUE NAME=""CoordinateZ"" TYPE=""Double"">528</VALUE>", "<VALUE NAME=""CoordinateZ"" TYPE=""Double"">530.75</VALUE>")
                originalOcalcFile = Regex.Replace(originalOcalcFile, "<VALUE NAME=""DiameterOrWidthInInches"" TYPE=""Double"">12</VALUE>", "<VALUE NAME=""DiameterOrWidthInInches"" TYPE=""Double"">9.6</VALUE>")
                originalOcalcFile = Regex.Replace(originalOcalcFile, "<VALUE NAME=""DepthInInches"" TYPE=""Double"">8</VALUE>", "<VALUE NAME=""DepthInInches"" TYPE=""Double"">6.9</VALUE>")
                originalOcalcFile = Regex.Replace(originalOcalcFile, "<VALUE NAME=""HeightInInches"" TYPE=""Double"">24</VALUE>", "<VALUE NAME=""HeightInInches"" TYPE=""Double"">18.5</VALUE>")
                originalOcalcFile = Regex.Replace(originalOcalcFile, "<VALUE NAME=""Weight"" TYPE=""Double"">71</VALUE>", "<VALUE NAME=""Weight"" TYPE=""Double"">45</VALUE>")

            End If

        Next

        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(saveAsNameAndLocation, originalOcalcFile, True)

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageServices.DisplayMessage(Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64), "Error Finding and Replacing!", "Please ensure you are connected to the Network and try again.", My.Resources.msbExclamation)

    End Try

End Sub
```

[image: Diff_Checker]

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot I can see that "DescriptionOverride" is always the first VALUE in ATTRIBUTES.

If above is always true and you want to replace only for "Nokia AEUB" entries, then check the "regex sandbox" with familiar case: https://regexr.com/5dd2l
(on site: if ERROR occurred due to 250 ms timeout, switch to "Tests" then back to "Text").

I've used:

```
"(<VALUE NAME="DescriptionOverride" TYPE="String">Nokia AEUB[\S\s]*?)<\/GenericEquipment>"
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27301455)

Comment: Thank you for the reply but that expression does not appear to produce any matches. Added a picture for better understanding....

Comment: I've improved my answer according to added screenshots.